# Python- Parser the today's date out of Dateutil

Tags: python-3.4, python-dateutil

I am working with Dateutil module in Python 3.4.1, and I'm trying to extract only the date part out of the code. For example

```
from datetime import *
date.today()
```

Results in:

```
datetime.date(2014, 8, 2)
```

Is there a way to remove the front part and use the remaining numbers as a text or string? I'm trying to use this in conjunction with Tkinter's entry widgets, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from datetime import *
today = date.today()
print(today.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
```

will result in

```
'2014-08-03'
```

Have a look at http://strftime.net/ for formatting help.

Comment: Thanks! I haven't seen this method yet while going through Dateutil posts.

Comment: You are using datetime (not dateutil) here, have a look at https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html